# angular ui-grid change row height creates checkbox bug

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have created ui-grid with sub grid, sub grid rows height was modified by css:

```css
   .expandableRow  .ui-grid-row, .expandableRow .ui-grid-    cell,.expandableRow .ui-grid-cell .ui-grid-vertical-bar
 {
    height: auto!important;
    }
```

when I am enabling row selection ( enableRowSelection:true) for the sub grid and when my row have multiple rows inside (since I changed my row height) my checkboxes are duplicated. 
[image]screen shot attached

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you got any answer, Im also looking for same :(